# What kind of paint should I use on the hinges and hardware of an exterior door?

Tags: paint, exterior, front-door

I've stripped and painted an entry door.  What kind of paint should I use to paint the hinges and hardware?

Comment: Hinge paint is a mixed blessing. Yes it matches, but sooner or later, the paint (or more likely repaint) interferes with the operation. And paint on hinges tends to chip off. Do you *really* need to paint or could you pick a hinge finish that can work with the door?

Answer (score 1):

Spray paint made for metal.  Take hardware off to get a professional look.

Comment: Any particular kind?

Comment: I use rustoleum.  Just do very light coats and spray a good 8-12 inches away.  You can always add more coats.

Comment: Need to really clean before spraying for good adhesion.